# facebook style hashtag system, preg_replace error

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have checked out a tutorial based on the facebook hashtag system, upon inserting this code I have noticed there is an error in the preg_replace function to make links clickable.

```
<?php

function convert_clickable_links($message) {
$parsedMessage = preg_replace(array('/(?i)\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»""'']))/', '/(^|[^a-z0-9_])@([a-z0-9_]+)/i', '/(^|[^a-z0-9_])#([a-z0-9_]+)/i'), array('<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', '$1<a href="">@$2</a>', '$1<a href="index.php?hashtag=$2">#$2</a>'), $message);
return $parsedMessage;
}
$message = '#test #test #test this is a hashtag test';
echo convert_clickable_links($message);
?>
```

for some reason in dreamweaver i get a syntax error, and when I uploaded the code I receive zero posts because the fucntion is broken. I cant seem to figure it out at all. Was wondering if anyone could help.

Comment: What are you passing as `$message` to this function?

Comment: @fboes: scroll a few miles to the right, and you'll find out.

Comment: I'd really love to see what the infamous syntax error is.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify my question was: What is the data you supply to this function (and thus is passed to `preg_replace`.

Comment: theres no actual error, it just highlights the code as red in dreamweaver which means that something is wrong. also it doesn't let me retrieve my status updates now. so its broken i guess..

Comment: Hm, executing this code does not give me any errors with `echo(convert_clickable_links('Test Test Test'));`

Comment: @fboes i used this as text '#testing new #hashtag code, working great! '

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on a LIVE site and you'll see them, **if** it does in fact contain syntax errors.

Comment: This worked fine for me `$message = "<a href='page.php'>#Hey #there!</a>"; echo convert_clickable_links($message);` - Is that how you're using your function or similar?

Comment: no it would be $message = '#test #test #test this is a hashtag test'; 
and then the convert clickable links function would turn those into links.

Comment: also it gave no errors with error reporting on

Comment: Again, using `$message = '#test #test #test this is a hashtag test';` worked fine for me. HTML source reads as `<a href="?hashtag=test">#test</a> <a href="?hashtag=test">#test</a> <a href="?hashtag=test">#test</a> this is a hashtag test` - So I don't know what your expected results should be.

Comment: i have no idea why its not working for me.. im receiving no output. just a blank page

Comment: If you're trying to run this off your own computer without a Webserver and PHP installed, and trying to run it as a regular (HTML) file that a web browser reads, then that's the problem.

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/ntjelhv here is my link. just a simple test file with the function in question. there is no error and no output text

Comment: Place the code from that file in your question so I can see what you're using. I can't tell by just viewing that link online.

Comment: ok i have put it in the question

Comment: Consult my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's these

`<>?«»""'']`

which should be changed to `<>?«»“”‘’]`

full (fixed) line:

```
$parsedMessage = preg_replace(array('/(?i)\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/', '/(^|[^a-z0-9_])@([a-z0-9_]+)/i', '/(^|[^a-z0-9_])#([a-z0-9_]+)/i'), array('<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', '$1<a href="">@$2</a>', '$1<a href="index.php?hashtag=$2">#$2</a>'), $message);
```

Having [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) on would have thrown:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '']))/'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in /index.php on line 4

---

HTML source:

```
<a href="index.php?hashtag=test">#test</a> <a href="index.php?hashtag=test">#test</a> <a href="index.php?hashtag=test">#test</a> this is a hashtag test
```

---

OP:

> it has been solved by escaping the characters which you have isolated - `,<>?«»""\'\']`

---

Escaping the single quotes, resolved the issue.

```
,<>?«»""\'\']
```

Comment: still does not work, sorry.. thank you so much for trying though

Comment: @morty You're welcome, but that is really strange because it tested ok for me. See my edit / reload under HTML source.

Comment: i think i fixed it by simply removing ""'' from <>?«»""'']

Comment: @morty Great! I'm glad to hear that.

Comment: it has been solved by escaping the characters which you have isolated - ,<>?«»""\'\']

Comment: @morty Ah, even better, thanks for the update. Glad it got resolved, *cheers*